# Oraganise Text into Sentences

Tags: php, regex

So I have some text:

This is a sentence. This is another sentence. This is a third sentence.

Any I'm trying to find a way to get each sentence into an array or on a new line. Something like this:

[0] => This is a sentence.

[1] =>This is another sentence.

[2] =>This is a third sentence.

I realise this is hard to do, but it doesn't have to be full proof. So it's OK if I get the odd value consisting of just a word or half a sentence when it's been split at the wrong place. So, basically I need to split at ".", "?" and "!".

I've played around with preg_match_all() but I'm struggling to get my head around the regular expressions.

This is what I have so far, but it doesn't work. My knowledge of regex is very shaky as you can tell. If someone could point me in the right direction I'd be very grateful. Thank you.

```
<?php

$string = "This is a sentence. This is another sentence. This is a third sentence .";

preg_match_all('/\.(.*)>\./', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I added the condition that a sentence should start with an uppercase letter.  It won't capture multiple punctuation at the end.

```
preg_match_all('/[A-Z][^!?.]+[!?.]/', $string, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```